# Getting a list of all computer objects in each AD domain

Tags: logging, powershell

So I wrote this script and although it does work I can't help but think that it can be more efficient with all the repetitive code. Can anyone offer any suggestions on making it fewer lines and eliminating the repeat lines?

```
$Domains = (Get-ADForest).domains | %{Get-ADDomain $_ | Select DistinguishedName,ReplicaDirectoryServers}

#Gets list of all Computer objects in each domain
foreach ($Domain in $Domains){
Write-Output "Working on $($Domain.DistinguishedName)"
  #Iterates through Computer array
   foreach ($Comp in (Get-ADComputer -Server $($Domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers[0]) -SearchBase $($Domain.DistinguishedName) -filter {OperatingSystem -notlike "*Server*"} -Properties     Name,LastLogonDate,DistinguishedName| ?{ $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Disabled*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Servers*"}|Select     Name,LastLogonDate,DistinguishedName)){
      #Performs test on date, if date is greater then $Days moves to $OU.
      if(((New-TimeSpan -Start ($Comp.LastLogonDate) -End (Get-Date)).days) -gt $Days -and $Exclusion -notcontains $Comp.name){
         $Computers += $Comp
         #Finds what OU each object should go to.  Checks if object is already in dumpster OU
         if($($domain.DistinguishedName) -like "*DomainA*"){
         Write-Output ((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm:ss') + ": Moved $($comp.DistinguishedName) to $DomainAOUDump") | Out-File $log -Append
         Move-ADObject -Identity $comp.DistinguishedName -Server $($Domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers[0]) -TargetPath $DomainAOUDump 
         }
         elseif($($domain.DistinguishedName) -like "*DomainB*"){
         Write-Output ((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm:ss') + ": Moved $($comp.DistinguishedName) to $DomainBOUDump") | Out-File $log -Append 
         Move-ADObject -Identity $comp.DistinguishedName -Server $($Domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers[0]) -TargetPath $DomainBOUDump
         }
         elseif($($domain.DistinguishedName) -like "*DomainC*"){ 
         Write-Output ((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm:ss') + ": Moved $($comp.DistinguishedName) to $DomainCOUDump") | Out-File $log -Append
         Move-ADObject -Identity $comp.DistinguishedName -Server $($Domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers[0]) -TargetPath $DomainCOUDump
         }
         elseif($($domain.DistinguishedName) -like "*DomainD*"){
         Write-Output ((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm:ss') + ": Moved $($comp.DistinguishedName) to $DomainDOUDump") | Out-File $log -Append
         Move-ADObject -Identity $comp.DistinguishedName -Server $($Domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers[0]) -TargetPath $DomainDOUDump
         }
         else{
         Write-Output ((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm:ss') + ": I don't know where $($comp.name) should be moved") | Out-File $log -Append
         }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'd start by trading that stack of if/elseif/else statements for a Switch.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers!

Answer (score 6):

One thing that I notice, you can change this repetitive fragment

```
if($($domain.DistinguishedName) -like "*DomainA*"){
    Write-Output ((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy:hh:mm:ss') + ": Moved $($comp.DistinguishedName) to $DomainAOUDump") | Out-File $log -Append
    Move-ADObject -Identity $comp.DistinguishedName -Server $($Domain.ReplicaDirectoryServers[0]) -TargetPath $DomainAOUDump 
}
```

Into the following (minus some variable definitions, e.g. `$TimeStamp`):

```
$DomainPrefix = Get-DomainPrefix $Domain
$TargetPath = Get-Variable -Name "Domain$($DomainPrefix)OUDump"

Write-Output "$TimeStamp: Moved $DistinguishedName to $TargetPath" | Out-File $log -Append
Move-ADObject -Identity $DistinguishedName -Server $Server -TargetPath $TargetPath
```

with `Get-DomainPrefix` defined to capture the first character after "Domain", e.g.

```
Function Get-DomainPrefix([String] $DomainName){
    $DomainName -match "Domain(?<Prefix>.)" | Out-Null
    $Matches.Prefix
}
```

So, the script will become (minus definition for necessary functions to hide the complexity)

```
foreach ($Domain in Get-Domains) {
    foreach ($Comp in (Get-ComputerArray -Domain $Domain)) {
        if ( ShouldBeMoved -Computer $Comp ) {
            $DomainPrefix = Get-DomainPrefix $Domain
            $TargetPath = Get-Variable -Name "Domain$($DomainPrefix)OUDump"
            $TimeStamp = Get-TimeStamp
            $CompName = $Comp.DistinguishedName
            $Server = Get-Server

            Write-Output "$TimeStamp: Moved $CompName to $TargetPath" | Out-File $log -Append
            Move-ADObject -Identity $CompName -Server $Server -TargetPath $TargetPath
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `else` clause is not handled in the simplified script above.

For further cleaning, you can redefine how you store the `$TargetPath` into a more friendly structure so that we don't need to use `Get-Variable`. Perhaps a map from `DomainPrefix` to the `TargetPath`.

Note: I'm not familiar with ADObject and stuff, so the variable naming might be a little off.